# Angular and images, a 10 kb image destroy the performance score

Tags: angular, image, lighthouse

in my Angular application I have the following image tag:

```
<img src="https://myImgKitKey.cloudimg.io/ik.imagekit.io/myCloudImgKey/myFolder/myImg.webp?width=400&q=75" width="400" height="190"/>
```

Everything seems perfect and, if I try to open directly the link of the image in a browser, and I download it and check the size, the size is just 10Kb! So, nothing.

Nevertheless, the performance index of the application (measured by the Lighthouse tool of Chrome) decrease dramatically from 98% to 91%, and just by adding that image.

Everything is well configured:

1. As is visible from the url, I used some cloud service in order to optimise the size of the image (and the final image has just a dimension of 10 kb)
2. I already tried both prefetch and preconnect in the index.html file

How can I keep the performance index heigh even with that image? How is possible that a 10kb image decrease the performance score of almost 10 points?

[image: Performance with the img tag]

[image: Performance without the img tag]